# Conservative magneto-static field on a current carrying wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetostatics, conservative-field

[image: magneto-static field around wire]

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{B}=0$$

I am asking why although magneto-static $B$ fields in total are considered as [non-conservative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force) fields by most of the literature, the magnetic field of a d.c. current carrying wire clearly shows a zero curl $\nabla \times \mathbf{B}=0$ [irrotational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field) field (i.e. consists of concentric circular magnetic flux) therefore is unambiguously a conservative field?

Is this an exception of the rule? Or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field of the wire in the magnetostatic case is $\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0 \mathbf{j}$ (Ampere's law). Therefore the expression you give is not valid on a region including the current carrying wire ($\mathbf{j} \ne 0$). However, you can define a scalar potential for a simply connected region which does not include the wire. The value would be proportional to the energy of a (hypothetical) magnetic monopole.

Comment: Oh yes of course! You are telling that this is not the total magnetic field of the wire? I did not include the magnetic field inside the wire which is obviously non-zero curl $\nabla \times \mathbf{B} \neq 0$ ! Silly mistake. Thank you so much!